# Normalization of SQL Database with similar data managed by different tools

Tags: sql, database-design, database-normalization

I'm designing a database for storing a bunch of product data that is both pulled via an API and scraped off the web.  This scraper will pull some data that is static and some data that varies with time. Therefore there will one table for each type of data (static/variable).  I'm trying to decide if there should be a separate table for variable data that is scraped compared to variable data that is pulled through an API.

At first, I thought they should be stored in separate tables because they are managed by separate tools.  However, data will be pulled through the API and scraped on the same schedule (daily), and so they will both be mapped with the same ProductID and date.  So, it seems like I could just combine the schema of both tables to save on the join time during queries for processing the data later.  The obvious downside to this is managing whether rows need to be created or updated whenever one of the processes runs (which of the scraper vs API tools create or update rows).

For what it's worth, these scripts will be pulling data for millions (maybe tens of millions) of rows per day, and storing it for quite a while.  So, the tables are going to get quite huge, and that's why I'm concerned with join times later on.

Here's an example in case this is all a little cloudy as an example.  There are multiple industries for this, but I'll just use real estate:
Scraped Static Data: ProductID, Address, City, State, Zip, SquareFeet, etc.
Scraped Variable Data: ProductID, Price, PricePerSqFt, etc.
API Variable Data: ProductID, PageHits, UniqueVisitors, etc.

Mainly just the variable data is the concern here.  So, just summarize, separate tables for the sake of general design principles, or one table for the sake of speed on joins?

Thanks in advance for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you give indicates that, apart from having 2 or 3 tables, you should also consider having just one table for both static and variable data. As long as the key of everything is just the product id, you can keep all information describing a particular id value in one record. Or do you intend to have a time stamp as part of the key of your variable data?

Once this has been decided, I can't see any advantage in having more tables than necessary.

- The joins you mention won't be particularly complicated, as they basically mean to read a single record from each of your tables, each time using a primary key, which is fast. But still reading 3 records means more effort than reading 2, or only one.
- There is no general design principle saying you should have a separate table for each way to collect data. On the contrary, it's the purpose of a database to contain data according to their logical structure without (too much) regard of the technical means of collecting or accessing them.
- The logic to decide whether to insert or update a row isn't complicated. Also, if you want to verify your data, you might need some logic anyway, e.g. making sure that variable data only get inserted for an object that already has static data.

Comment: The variable data will also be keyed with a timestamp. I forgot to add that in the example schema.  It just seemed like it wouldn't make sense to keep the variable and static data in the same table since the static data would be repeated in every row of the same item, which seems unnecessary. So, with the keying by date, would you then recommend two tables, or still consider just one? Thanks for the response

Comment: When the timestamp is part of the key, i.e. you intend to have more than one variable data record for each product record, then variable data need to be in a separate table to avoid the redundancy of static data.